# 3.5 Inch RPi LCD with colors problem

Tags: display, raspberry-pi-os

I've just installed a 3.5 Inch RPi LCD (A) V3 (XPT2046 Touch Controller) on my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ and I'm having problems with the colors of the display. I'm attaching an image to show you.

[image: RPI Image]

I'm using the driver from this link: https://www.elecrow.com/wiki/index.php?title=3.5_Inch_480x320_TFT_Display_with_Touch_Screen_for_Raspberry_Pi
and my OS is Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) with desktop (from may 2020).

The touch is working, the problem is only with the colors.

[image: Board]

Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: the colors look ok to me ... the picture does not show any failure

Comment: I'm with the same issue, already tried different OS and configurations but nothing... Also change the power source but no effect.... @jsotola, the problem is with the colors, it seems all colors are inverted.

Comment: Seems any configuration problem, because when booting, the correct colors are showed and change after a while. Take a look [here](https://youtu.be/MBlq891USc0)

Comment: Interesting @KoopaKiller. In my case, it already starts with inverted colors.

Comment: Weird... I've sent a msg to the seller, but i didn't receive any answer.

Comment: Please, let me know if the seller answers you how to figure out this problem.

Comment: It looks to me like the display is working.  I guess the colors are set by ANSI escape sequences issued by the software using the display.  On my RPi, the prompt is similarly colored (but black background, green user@host, and blue prompt).  You can issue command ( echo "$PS1" | hexdump -C ) to see the escape sequences in your prompt (set by environment varaible PS1).  You should be able to find a lot of advice on how to set output colors in Debian/Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After dug deep into google searchs, finally i got it worked...
I was noticed that there are some variations of this LCD and each of them work with a specific driver...

I' ve tested a lot of configurations and OS (Raspibian, Ubuntu, RetroPie etc..) and got it works in Raspbian latest version with a script called **LCD35-show.sh** from [this](https://github.com/waveshare/LCD-show) repo. I' ve tested all of them and only this one works for me.

Some others references that helped me:

https://diy.2pmc.net/3-5-inch-lcd-tft-screen-raspberry-pi-display-touch-install-fix-inverted-colors/

https://futurice.com/blog/id-like-to-have-some-lcd-on-my-pi (Touch calibration)

Comment: It didn't work for me. I still have the inverted color. When you plug in the Raspberry to the power supply without the flash drive, is your screen white? It is very weird for me, never saw a screen with a white background on stand by

Comment: @GabrielSchubert Yes, the screen still white until the system initiate. But, I had a problem some days ago, after update the OS, the LCD stopped  to work, and after reapply the driver still doesn't work... this generic LCD it's a really pain... i'm about to put it in the trash and buy another one from weaveshare or adafruit.

Comment: Yes! I'm really thinking about giving up on this and buy a new one from waveshare. I got this almost working with LCD35B-show-V2, but still orange and blue color inverted. I will keep this way by now

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me
http://www.lcdwiki.com/3.5inch_RPi_Display

This 3.5" LCD module is neither from Waveshare nor Elecrow